# Setting a sliding menu on click listener

Tags: android, menu, onclicklistener, slidingmenu

In this program I implemented the [sliding menu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). The problem that I am having now is setting up the on click listeners for these menus.

The library requires the menu to be a different layout, or atleast that is the way that I have implemented it. What I would like to achieve now is to implement various onClick listeners to these menu options.

The program looks like this(a short part of it):

**menu.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/ask_a_question"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:onClick="getQuestion">

        <TextView android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ask_a_question"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <ImageView android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ask_a_question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/question"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and on its **MainActivity.java** the program looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu);

        getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(100);

        ask_a_question = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ask_a_question);
        ask_a_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getQuestion();
            }
        });
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.log_in_button);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.btshome.LOGINACTIVITY"));
            }
        });
    }

    public Intent getQuestion()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.btshome.ASKPAGE");
        startActivity(i);
        return null;
    }
```

which returns the following error:

```
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.btshome.ASKPAGE }
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.example.btshome.MainActivity.getQuestion(MainActivity.java:47)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.example.btshome.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-23 19:43:30.030: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The manifest page:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.btshome.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.btshome.LOGINACTIVITY"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SignUp"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.btshome.SIGNUP"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoginPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.btshome.LOGINPAGE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".QuestionAsking"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.btshome.ASKPAGE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

Is the approach that I taking to implement this menu item on click good? or is it a bad way to go about it, because I will have to have the sliding menu available on all my pages. Help Please.

Comment: Do you need to use Actions as you do it now? Or just opening the `Activity` would be enough for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't have `ASKPAGE` Activity in your manifest file.

In AndroidManifest.xml, inside `application` tag, add:

```
<activity android:name=".ASKPAGE">
```

EDIT:

Your `getQuestion()` method should look like this:

```
public Intent getQuestion()
{
    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.btshome.ASKPAGE"); // Set an action in constructor
    i.setClass(MainActivity.this, QuestionAsking.class);  // Set an Activity class
    startActivity(i);
    return null;
}
```

And just a note - I hope you see that you always return `null` in this method.

Comment: new error:
04-23 20:31:38.371: E/AndroidRuntime(892): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.btshome/com.example.btshome.QuestionAsking}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Both setBehindContentView must be called in onCreate in addition to setContentView.

Comment: Well now the problem is in `QuestionAsking` Activity, you should paste its code.

Comment: i think i found the error. The QuestionAsking activity did not have the following LOCs: setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu);   getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(100);

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly declare an intent filter in at least one of your activities that will handle your intent. For more information you can check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). As an example you should do something like:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.btshome.LoginActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.btshome.LOGINACTIVITY" />>

                <category android:name="com.example.btshome />
</activity>
```

Comment: Yes indeed. I didn't notice that you uploaded the manifest too.